# Loop AnimatorSet

Tags: android, animation

I have made an AnimatorSet of three ObjectAnimator which I want to repeat sequentally.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="5"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:duration="600"
        android:valueFrom="5"
        android:valueTo="-5"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueFrom="-5"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

</set>
```

But if I set the CycleInterpolator to AnimatorSet because the Animators will start sequentally

> public void setInterpolator (TimeInterpolator interpolator)
>   Added in API level 11
>
> Sets the TimeInterpolator for all current child animations of this AnimatorSet.

So I tried looping by restarting AnimatorSet by setting a listener, but it stops for few milliseconds and the effect of restarting AnimatorSet is noticeable.

```
a.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
    {
        animation.start();
    }
});
```

What can I do to loop it (except building a huge list of ObjectAnimators or writing my own animation using Thread and Handler)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround for this particular case is creating an AnimatorSet with first item to rotate one half and the second to keep rotating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:duration="150"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-5"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:duration="300"
        android:valueFrom="-5"
        android:valueTo="5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

</set>
```

Answer (score 7):

In desperate need of this feature too, turns out some one already have found the solution.

http://www.jefflinwood.com/2013/04/repeating-android-animations-with-animatorset/

All credit belongs to the original author.

```
mAnimationSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
    mAnimationSet.start();
}

});
mAnimationSet.start();
```

Comment: I remember I tried that. That had produced a small but noticeable delay whenever it is restarted.

Comment: @DoctororDrive just polished one of my project with this method(on Kindle Fire HDX, fade-in, fade-out, then loop again), no delay observed for my part.

Comment: To address this problem, we may [vote on Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36929638) and demand that AnimatorSet supports `repeatMode` and `repeatCount` XML attributes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a repeat mode to the AnimationSet, see:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:repeatMode

Comment: You are referring to Animation. Animator object has no such method.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice. So you can programatically create AnimatorSet that contains many times the same instance of your XML-defined AnimatorSet, or as pskink suggests make a custom looping interpolator. I would use modulus instead of sine

Comment: I tried <set> in <set> but it applies the Interpolator for all children. And new AnimatorSet with Interpolator + inflated AnimatorSet just does not repeat.

Comment: @Doctoror Drive you just want your object rotate CW then CCW and finally CW, right? so dont overcomplicate this and use custom interpolator

Comment: @ognian its not loop interpolator, it is just interpolator that makes what OP wanted to achieve using 3 object animators and it does it smoothly in contrary to OP solution

Answer (score -2):

just ask it to repeat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:ordering="sequentially"
   android:repeatMode="reverse"
   android:repeatCount="infinite">
```

=)

count can also be a defined number.

Comment: You are referring to Animation. Animator object has no such method.

Comment: yes it does: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#INFINITE

Comment: ValueAnimator has, but I am using an AnimatorSet (which extends Animator, not ValueAnimator).

Comment: repeatCount in <set> of res/animator/ xmls does not work. Just tried.